# CryptDecrypt works but returns error 0x80090005

Tags: c, windows, encryption, cryptdecrypt

I have a problem with the following code (which decrypts a file using a known key):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

void error(const char *what) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s failed with last error 0x%x\n", what, GetLastError());
    exit(1);
}

#define AES_KEY_SIZE 32

typedef struct {
    BLOBHEADER hdr;
    DWORD dwKeySize;
    BYTE rgbKeyData[AES_KEY_SIZE];
} AES256KEYBLOB;

BYTE *hex2byte(const char *hex) {
    int len = strlen(hex) / 2;
    BYTE *bytes = malloc(len);
    if (bytes == NULL) {
        error("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }
    unsigned char val[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sscanf(&hex[i * 2], "%2hhx", &val);
        bytes[i] = val[0];
    }
    return bytes;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <input_file> <output_file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE *key = hex2byte("c2ecf7a4f3d1620f18cd38379269948fcd3aaf4fdce6d50d310464ea823a");

    AES256KEYBLOB aes256KeyBlob;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.reserved = 0;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;
    aes256KeyBlob.dwKeySize = AES_KEY_SIZE;
    memcpy(aes256KeyBlob.rgbKeyData, key, AES_KEY_SIZE);

    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    if (!CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        error("CryptAcquireContext");
    }

    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    if (!CryptImportKey(hProv, (BYTE *) &aes256KeyBlob, sizeof(AES256KEYBLOB), 0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        error("CryptImportKey");
    }

    DWORD numBytes = 0;
    if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, NULL, &numBytes, 0)) {
        error("CryptEncrypt");
    }

    FILE *input_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!input_file) {
        perror("Error opening input file");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output_file = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (!output_file) {
        perror("Error opening output file");
        fclose(input_file);
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE blk[numBytes];
    while (fread(blk, 1, numBytes, input_file) == numBytes) {

        if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, blk, &numBytes)) {
            //error("CryptDecrypt");
        }

        fwrite(blk, 1, numBytes, output_file);
    }

    free(key);
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);

    return 0;
}
```

This code WORKS, but I had to comment the error checking line:

```
//error("CryptDecrypt");
```

I tried as suggested in other stackoverflow solution to increase the buffer size but it does not help.
I don't care much because the code works, but I wish to understand the reason and how to avoid it.
Note if I use:

```
CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, FALSE, 0, blk, &numBytes)
```

I get no error but it works only for the first block.

Please don't mark this as a duplicate because none of the solutions work.

Comment: Well, what additional information do you get from `GetLastError`? That's supposed to tell you why exactly you got a non-zero return value. Also setting `Final` to `TRUE` always seem weird ...

Comment: It does not say anything.. that error just means the key is wrong (NTE_BAD_DATA) but that's not true.
Infact the program works.

Comment: `sscanf(&hex[i * 2], "%2hhx", &val);` That reads a single `unsigned char`. You don't need an array for that. Also, `val` has wrong type. It is pointer to array of `unsigned char`, not pointer to `unsigned char` as `val` is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the encryption code was not posted, it is not clear how the ciphertext was generated. A test shows that a decryption with the posted code is only possible under the described conditions if the ECB mode was used (a decryption of a ciphertext generated with CBC fails).

The following changes are necessary in the posted code for a proper and error message-free decryption:

- The current code uses the default mode, which is CBC with a Zero-IV (16 0x00 Bytes). Therefore, an explicit switch to the ECB mode is required:

  ```c
  // Set ECB mode
  DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_ECB;
  if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_MODE, (BYTE*)&dwMode, 0)) {
      error("CryptSetKeyParam");
  }
  ```
- Also, the size of the ciphertext is determined incorrectly. This is due to the fact that `CryptEncrypt()` is used for the determination, which is actually intended for determining the ciphertext size during encryption (the ciphertext is generally larger than the plaintext due to the padding) and not for decryption.
  The ciphertext size can be determined via the file size, e.g.

  ```c
  // Get ciphertext size
  fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
  DWORD ctSize = ftell(input_file);
  fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
  ```

  Debugging the posted code shows that due to the incorrect use of `CryptEncrypt()` `numBytes` corresponds to the block size (i.e. 16 bytes), so that the data is read and decrypted block by block. Presumably the use of a chunk size of 16 bytes is not intended, but a larger chunk size or the reading of the file as a whole.
- Although the file is read and decrypted block by block, the final flag is set to `TRUE` for all chunks. This must be changed so that the final flag is set to `FALSE` for all chunks and `TRUE` only for the last chunk, e.g. as in the following code:

  ```c
  // Read chunks
  const DWORD chunkSize = 64; // multiple  of 16
  BYTE buffer[chunkSize];
  DWORD dataLen = chunkSize;
  DWORD read = 0;
  while (read < ctSize) {
      dataLen = fread(buffer, 1, chunkSize, input_file);
      read += dataLen;
      if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, !(read < ctSize) , 0, buffer, &dataLen)) { // final flag = FALSE except for the last chunk
          error("CryptDecrypt");
      }
      fwrite(buffer, 1, dataLen, output_file);
  }
  ```

With this, decryption is performed correctly and no more error message is displayed.

---

Why did the decryption still work with the code posted in the question (apart from the error message)? After all, the CBC mode with a Zero-IV is used by default, which is actually not compatible with the data generated in ECB mode.

The reason is: As already stated above, the ciphertext is read and decrypted block by block in the posted code. The final flag is set to `TRUE` for all blocks. A `TRUE` sets the IV back to the initial state (i.e. to a Zero-IV). In addition, encrypting a *single* block in CBC mode with a Zero-IV results in the same ciphertext as encrypting the same block in ECB mode. For this reason, every block is successfully decrypted.
On the other hand, a `TRUE` for the final flag also means an unpadding is performed. This generally fails (as only the last block is padded), which leads to an error with the error code *0x80090005 (Error: Bad Data)*.
The overall result is an error message with otherwise successful decryption.

However, if you now try to avoid unpadding by setting the final flag for all blocks to `FALSE`, the error message is no longer triggered, but the ciphertext is decrypted incorrectly because the IV is no longer reset. In order for the ciphertext to be decrypted correctly again, the mode must be set to ECB. And to ensure that unpadding takes place for the last block, the final flag for the last block must be set to `TRUE`. This in turn leads to the above solution (with chunk size 16).

---

**Edit:**
In the comments, it turned out that you are looking for an equivalent to

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -in "encoded file" -out "decoded file" -nopad -K <hex key>
```

i.e. a decryption with ECB without padding. Since without padding the final flags of all blocks are to be set to `FALSE`, the loop can be simplified a little.
With regard to the performance issues mentioned in the comment: The above 64 bytes were intended for test purposes. For better performance choose a larger chunk size (to avoid unnecessarily many `fread()` calls), which is at the same time compatible with the available memory, e.g. 64 MB:

```c
DWORD chunkSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024; // choose a proper chunk size (a multiple of 16 bytes)
BYTE* buffer = (BYTE*)malloc(chunkSize); 
DWORD dataLen;
while ((dataLen = fread(buffer, 1, chunkSize, input_file)) > 0) {
    if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, FALSE, 0, buffer, &dataLen)) { 
        error("CryptDecrypt");
    }
    fwrite(buffer, 1, dataLen, output_file);
}
free(buffer);
```

Comment: yes. the code above works! it just gets an annoying error... that's all.

Comment: i ended up removing completely the microsoft implementation and used a very small and good implementation I found here: https://github.com/qistoph/ArduinoAES256/blob/master/aes256.cpp

which works beautifully.

Comment: and it's completely portable... I cross compiled it even for arm, for cygwin, msys and mingw :P

Comment: @Zibri - My answer refers to:  *...but I wish to understand the reason and how to avoid it...* and explains the reason: You bend a CBC decryption in such a way that you can decrypt a ciphertext generated with ECB. Incidentally, this can be achieved with any library. The problem is therefore not caused by the MS library, but it is simply an incorrectly implemented logic.

Comment: @Zibri - The correct logic can be easily implemented with the MS library (as described and with few changes), so there is no reason to switch to another library. Of course, there is nothing wrong with changing libraries if you prefer another one. However, it is not necessary with regard to the required functionality (decryption with AES/ECB/PKCS#7).

Comment: @Zibri - One more comment on your assessment that the decryption actually *works* and that *only* an annoying error message is generated. You really can't speak of a working code here. It only works with 16 bytes chunks, which is terribly *inefficient* (just think of larger files) and even then the data can be *corrupted* (namely if an unpadding is successful for an intermediate block because the data happens to match a valid padding).

Comment: I understand and you are right, but that's how those dumb f*cks at Samsung obfuscated the firmware of their SSD. See here: https://github.com/Zibri/Samsung-SSD-Firmware-Decrypt

Comment: I did the modifications you wrote and guess.. I got no error for all chunks but I got error at the last one :D

Comment: @Zibri - This error indicates that the unpadding of the last block with PKCS#5/PKCS#7 has failed. In this case, you can simply replace `!(read < ctSize)` with `FALSE` in `CryptDecrypt()`. Now no unpadding is performed for any block, not even for the last one.

Comment: @Zibri - Maybe your plaintext was simply not padded. This is rather unusual, but if the plaintext fulfills the length criterion (its length must be an integer multiple of the block size, i.e. 16 bytes for AES), padding is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Zibri - You can check this by comparing the lengths of the original plaintext and the ciphertext. If both are the same length, no padding was used; if the ciphertext is longer, padding was used. As I did not have any test data available, I assumed the most likely case, i.e. ECB with PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding. For this reason, I implemented an unpadding of the last block.

Comment: @Zibri - However, if your check reveals that a padding has been used, then the error means that a padding other than PKCS#5/PKCS#7 has been applied. You must then determine which padding or alternatively post (non-productive) test data, i.e. plaintext, ciphertext and key for a data analysis.

Comment: in reality, this command does the decrypt just fine:
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -d -in "encoded file" -out "decoded file" -nopad -K KEY
I just wanted to do the same in C..

Comment: @Zibri - This OpenSSL command decrypts with AES in ECB mode and does not use padding. That's exactly what the code in my answer does (with the last change from the comment, so with `FALSE` instead of `!(read < ctSize)`). You seem to think that's not the case, why?

Comment: yes. with FALSE works... ```!(read < ctSize)``` fails on the last one.

Comment: anyway the script ```sfwd2.sh``` which uses directly openssl is 10 times faster than the code above...

Comment: @Zibri - Before a performance test, the chunk size must be optimized. The 64 bytes were intended for test purposes (my test file was only 512 bytes in size and I tested several loop runs with the 64 bytes). I have added this to the answer.